# Parlsey prevent keydown validation after initial validation call

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I am validating a form using Parlsey like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit-form-btn", function(e) {
  $(".form-class").off().submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parsley().validate();
    if ($(this).parsley().isValid()) {
      //Do something
    }
  });
});
```

After the initial validation, validation checks appear to be calling on every "keydown" press. How can I only validate again when my ".submit-form-btn" is clicked on again? I only want validation checks on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the `data-parsley-trigger-after-failure` attribute with a value of `submit`. This will then ensure only submits will trigger further validation. You can either add it to individual fields (causing some fields to continue to validate on input while others will only validate on submit), or to the entire form (to specify submit-only validation everywhere):

`<form id="form" data-parsley-trigger-after-failure="submit">`

or:

`<input type="text" required data-parsley-trigger-after-failure="submit">`

[Here's a Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGeMvy)

Comment: Perfect answer. <3